# Matter.js - Is this the proper way to render more than 1 engine and canvas in a page?

Tags: javascript, html, matter.js

I'm trying to do what the image has shown, to have different canvas within a single page. Each of them has different properties and options. So far it works but

1. Is this a proper way to do it?
2. Will it be slow loading on a live server? I am experimenting it on a localhost atm.

[image]

// -------- FIRST Canvas -----

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

//Fetch our canvas
    var canvas = document.getElementById('world');
// module aliases
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
    Render = Matter.Render,
    World = Matter.World,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies;

// create an engine
var engine = Engine.create();

// create a renderer
var render = Render.create({
        canvas: canvas,
        engine: engine,
        options: {
            width: 500,
            height: 500,
            background: '#000',
            wireframes: false,
            showAngleIndicator: false
});

// create two boxes and a ground
var boxA = Bodies.rectangle(400, 200, 80, 80);
var boxB = Bodies.rectangle(450, 50, 80, 80);
var ground = Bodies.rectangle(400, 610, 810, 60, { isStatic: true });

// add all of the bodies to the world
World.add(engine.world, [boxA, boxB, ground]);

// run the engine
Engine.run(engine);

// run the renderer
Render.run(render);
  });
</script>


<canvas id="world"></canvas>
```

// -------- SECOND canvas -----

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

//Fetch our canvas
    var canvas = document.getElementById('world2');
// module aliases
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
    Render = Matter.Render,
    World = Matter.World,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies;

// create an engine
var engine = Engine.create();

// create a renderer
var render = Render.create({
        canvas: canvas,
        engine: engine,
        options: {
            width: 500,
            height: 500,
            background: '#000',
            wireframes: false,
            showAngleIndicator: false
});

// create two boxes and a ground
var boxA = Bodies.rectangle(400, 200, 80, 80);
var boxB = Bodies.rectangle(450, 50, 80, 80);
var ground = Bodies.rectangle(400, 610, 810, 60, { isStatic: true });

// add all of the bodies to the world
World.add(engine.world, [boxA, boxB, ground]);

// run the engine
Engine.run(engine);

// run the renderer
Render.run(render);
  });
</script>


<canvas id="world2"></canvas>
```

Comment: Seems proper enough to me. As for live deployment, all of the code runs on the user's machine. The server just delivers the code to the client as text, so there should be no performance difference relative to localhost beyond the initial load and whatever resource constraints and performance characteristics your clients may have on their local machines.